# Ruby on Rails "hot deploy" not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, webrick

I don't know if the correct title for this is hot deploy.
I am modifying controllers and views and I have to restart the server to view those changes.

Why? I think that it didn't worked like this.
I am using webrick server. Environment is development.

I am using Rails 3.1

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your config/environments/development.rb and make sure you have:

```
Railsapp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false      
  # ...
end
```

In mine, it comes with this explanatory comment:

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I remember that I changed this value because of a active_admin/devise/rails3 compatibility issue